Is it safe to have together mongo driver and spring data mongodb observability together?
This is question to Spring Data team reported according to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.adoc#using-github-issues
Of course anyone can answer.
According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/reference/observability/observability.html,

(...)if you wish to use Spring Data MongoDB’s flavor of Observability, you
must carry out the following steps.

Disable Spring Boot’s autoconfigured MongoDB command listener
management.metrics.mongo.command.enabled=false



What will be wrong if it will NOT not be disabled?
According to my simple experiment, it is possible to have both:

spring_data_mongodb_command_seconds_max{db_operation="insert"} 0.0030122
mongodb_driver_commands_seconds_max{command="insert"} 0.004177

As I understand, time required to perform operation, in the example "insert", is sum of time for waiting on connection and time of proper operation.
mongodb_driver_commands shows time of proper operation.
spring_data_mongodb_command shows time of waiting connection plus time of proper operation
I would like to monitor both.
PS. In given example time of waiting connection seems be negative. I think is millisecond precision issue.
